# Magento узнать роуты плагина

Tags: php, xml, magento

Добрый день, мне знакомый скинул плагин для магенту. Я уже разбираюсь с ним как час, и никак не могу понять где прописаны пути, на которых он действует. Я понял, что за это отвечает system.xml, но там я так же не смог найти путей. Прошу помочь и подсказать, где же все таки они находятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Роуты прописываются в файле config.xml в теге `<routers>`. Если в плагине такой тег не используется, значит роуты создаются автоматически из имен методов контроллеров.

Comment: Вот я нашел, https://pastebin.com/0jiZKjj1 . Мне надо вызвать Mage_Sales_DownloadController, который принимает гет запрос id, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Непонятный вопрос, вы хотите получить роут, который ведет к Mage_Sales_DownloadController? Какой метод принимает id?